# pandas str.extractall on complete words

Tags: python, regex, pandas, kaggle

I have a column of tweets. I want to get a list of all mentions inside the tweet using the regex:

```
\@(\w+)
```

I tried using `df.Tweets.str.extractall('\@(\w+)')` but it doesn't succeed with matching the entire word as it wants (my guess) to separate each word to many columns. I get the following error

```
AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 15 columns.
```

I'll say that `'\@(\w)'` works as expected and returns a result but only the first letter. the `+` for the entire word is probably the root.

This is the ISIS dataset from Kaggle. For example, the first match is on
`'Aslm Please share our new account after the previous one was suspended.@KhalidMaghrebi @seifulmaslul123 @CheerLeadUnited'`
using `.extract()` works fine but only finds the first one.
using `.extractall('\@(\w)')` I get:

```
             0
  match   
8     0      K
      1      s
      2      C
```

which makes sense. But extracting all the complete words gives an error.

Comment: the regex you're using and  `extractall` are the way to do.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the dataframe.  We can not tell unless you share it.

Comment: the df in question is the ISIS kaggle dataset.
First cell to match is `'@AbdirahmanBash2 @KhalidMaghrebi_ @IbnNabih1 @Polder_Mujahid  Aslm, we have completed the translation with the exception of a few news'`

Comment: Put that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently pandas looks to separate groups to columns so the solution is to wrap all the regex also as a group.
`df.Tweets.str.extractall('(\@(\w+))')`

difference being a wrapping parenthesis inside the string.

Comment: `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`